Geometry Nodes (4.1): How to randomize "hill" diameters
My Nodetree creates smooth hills on that green area. How can i randomize their radius?

randomizing the map range value that controls the radius of the hills
just creates some weird jitter.
trying to randomize other values like the geometry proximity distance
etc have similar results
maybe the random value needs some ID constraint. capturing the ID of the points that are the origin of the hills removes the jitter, but they are still all the same size



The entire tree for convenience:


you need a random position per vertex, which you separated. I generate a "unique" id by using xyz and multiplying and adding that:

